# How to Execute Scenario multiple times with different values specified in DataTables

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I want to Execute a scenario twice based on number of rows in data tables from code shown in below structure -

testfeature.feature

```
Feature: Fill Form

@Test_Site_Registration
Scenario Outline: Verify the registration

Then Enter Text 'fName' <fname>
Then Enter Text 'mName' <mname>
Then Enter Text 'lName' <lname>
Then Submit

Examples:

| fname | mname | lname |
| FnameTest1  | FnameTest1  | FnameTest1  |
| FnameTest2  | FnameTest2  | FnameTest2  |
```

testfeature.rb

```
Then /^Enter Text (.*) (.*)$/ do |fieldId|value|
  @browser.text_field(:id, fieldId).set(value)
end

Then (/^Submit$/) do
  @browser.element(:xpath,"../../../btn-- a sample xpath").when_present.click_no_timeout
end
```

Here I want to execute the scenario "Verify the registration" twice, as I have been passing 2 different values in data tables.

Please Note- 
I already wrote 2 different scenarios and executed.
However, for optimization and learning experience I want to know this answer.

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: Using a scenario outline is the right approach. Are you saying it is not working? If so, you need to be more specific about what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
Scenario Outline: Test Registration
Given Enter <fname>
Given Enter <mname>
Given Enter <lname>
Then Registration Process
Then Verify Registration
Examples: 
|fname|mname|lname|
|f1|f1|f1|
|f2|f2|f2|
```

This means that, for every new data row in the examples, all the GIVEN, WHEN, THEN steps will be repeated.

Comment: This is not what's expected, the expected answer was to explore how the two parameters can be accessed